# "And I'll tell you for why". Why the "for"?

Tags: phrases

English is my second language, so maybe I'm just missing something simple.

I've come across the phrase "and I'll tell you for why" a couple of times and I'm wondering why you'd say that instead of the shorter "and I'll tell you why". They seem to have the same meaning to me.

Why the extra "for"? Is the phrase used in all English speaking countries or is it British-English or England-English? I don't think I've ever heard an American use the phrase.

I've tried Googling for an explanation with no luck.

Edit: There's an example here, 2 seconds into the video: https://www.facebook.com/BBCOne/videos/the-man-with-the-golden-underwear-qi/1435374217356021/

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WhvbEh8Dv5g A 15-year-old YouTube video showing a British comedy TV show called Gavin & Stacy. The utterance comes at the 8 second mark

Comment: Nice find! I've linked a video in my question with another example. A third example I have is Sara Pascoe saying it on 8 Out Of 10 Cats, but I can't find the video.

Comment: Mark Twain's Tom Sawyer [*Soon as they come to think, they knowed there warn't no corpse. And **I'll tell you for why***](https://books.google.it/books?id=e1BODwAAQBAJ&pg=PT2001&lpg=I'll%20tell%20%22you%20for%20why%22&f=false) suggests it was quite common in certain American English dialects. I don't know if the same is true today.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Not really. That answer states that it's archaic and not in use which seems incorrect. I'm also asking if the 'for' changes the meaning and/or if it's a regional expression more than if it's proper or not.

Comment: @HansKilian it is not at all standard American dialect. I would say it's archaic and not in use on this side of the pond.

Comment: I've promoted @Kate Bunting's comment to answer status. I'd agree it's still used, but it's rare, old-fashioned, used to generate a 'homely', familiar rather than a clinical, formal tone. (And I'm speaking as a Brit with quite a few years' experience.)

Comment: This sounds like an error to me; I'm a native English speaker (in Canada, with some exposure to British usage) and it doesn't sound familiar or even correct to me.  You're not wrong for thinking this is weird.  If not for the comments and answers here, I'd have had no idea it was ever valid as a colloquial(?) usage.

Comment: @Mari-LouA When I saw the title, I immediately thought of Rob Brydon – I’ve definitely heard him use the phrase more than once, including in natural speech (i.e., interviews and game shows, rather than tv shows). It sounds distinctly Welsh to me, but that may be just because I associate it so much with Rob Brydon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They do have the same meaning. [This Ngrams search](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=for+why&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) shows that *for why* in place of simply *why* was moderately common in the 19th century and much less so in the 20th. It's just an 'old-fashioned' usage. I can't tell you why the graph shows a massive increase in recent years, but a lot of the results seem to be false positives such as "Daily wisdom for *Why does he do that?*" (a companion volume to another book), "Judaism's case for why persons matter" and so on.

Answer (score -1):

This is non-standard usage, possibly American dialect. I suppose it's a confusion between "for what" (for what reason did it happen? = why?) and "why" (similar meaning).

Logically, it does make sense ("for what reason?") but it isn't really standard English. It sounds dialectal.

Comment: I've added a video to my question with someone British saying it on a panel show

Comment: Nope, not American

Comment: Really? What makes you think that's a non-standard usage, possibly American dialect?

Comment: Robbie: "what makes me think" it's non-standard or dialect is 40 years of native speech (spoken and heard).